# How Do I Count days since I wrote in something in a cell using VBA for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim validationRange As Range
    Dim customValue As Variant

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Define the range where the data validation is applied (e.g., column B)
    Set validationRange = Me.Range("B2:B100")

    ' Check if the changed cell is within the validation range
    If Not Intersect(target, validationRange) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' Prevent triggering the event again
        
        For Each cell In target
            If cell.Value = "Other" Then
                ' Prompt the user for a custom value
                customValue = InputBox("Please enter a custom value for 'Other':", "Custom Value")
                
                ' Check if the user didn't cancel the InputBox
                If customValue <> "" Then
                    cell.Value = customValue
                Else
                    cell.ClearContents
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End If

    If Not Intersect(target, Me.Range("A2:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In target
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = 0
            Else
                cell.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
            End If
            
        Next cell
    End If

ExitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' Ensure events are always re-enabled
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

The code at the bottom makes it so when I write something in the A column, a zero is made in the C column. I want to furthermore make it so as the days pass, the number becomes greater.
How can I do that?

Im new to via so I don't know the variables needed.

Comment: Is the pattern if 1 day passes, 0 becomes 1, and if two days pass, 1 becomes 2? This will be a lot easier if the logic includes writing a timestamp.

Comment: Hi, That is how I would like to have the program work! I am making it this complicated so that I can hone my skills in the art of VBA. I originally had it completed and programmed as a time stamp, but I wanted to figure out how to make it a dynamic countdown instead where it references the original date something is typed and then in counts the days that have passed.

Comment: Worth noting that just because `If Not Intersect(target, validationRange) Is Nothing` passes, it doesn't mean that *all cells* in `Target` are inside of the range `validationRange` - only that there's at least one cell in the intersection. You should loop over the intersection, not over `Target`

Comment: Write a formula eg:  `cell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=TODAY()-DATEVALUE(""" & Format(Date,"yyyy-mm-dd") & """)"`

Answer (score 0):

Because Excel doesn't automatically track changes, you'll need to create a system to keep track on when edits occur and calculate the time elapsed.

To build upon the code you've already developed, instead of inserting '0' into the cell, consider placing the current date in another cell. Then, apply a formula to the 'C' column as follows:

```
If Not Intersect(target, Me.Range("A2:A100")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cell In target
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Date
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=TODAY() - " & cell.Offset(0, 3).Address
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, 3).ClearContents
            cell.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
        End If
        
    Next cell
End If
```

By doing this, whenever you update the 'A' column, the event will automatically record the current date in the 'D' column and calculate the number of days that have passed in the 'C' column, just as you intended.